# How to change string to lower case inside Java Spring @PropertySource annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a statement

```
`@PropertySource("${env}.properties")`
```

where 'env' is my command line parameter.

If env=QA, this would result in my config file being named QA.properties.

**I want to ensure that the name of the config file is always in lower case (i.e. 'qa.properties)'.**

Answer (score 2):

you can use like spring expression language like this

```
@PropertySource("classpath:build.${env.toLowerCase()}.properties")
```

or something like

```
@PropertySource("classpath:build.${env}.toLowerCase().properties")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer however it does not work for me. 


Getting errors:
`'could not resolve placeholder 'env.toLowerCase()' in value "classpath..."'` in the first case, and `'class path resource [build.dev.toLowerCase().properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist'` in the second case.

Comment: try remove the build. part